# Flashing issue with the view while dragging in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, draggesture

I am planning to implement dragging of the entire view by dragging the `Image` view, but there is a flickering issue during the process. If I move the gesture code to the `ZStack`, the flickering disappears, but I need the operation to be limited to the `Image` only.

```swift
import SwiftUI
struct MyGestureView: View {
    var x: CGFloat = 200
    var y: CGFloat = 200
    @GestureState var dragGesture = CGSize.zero
    @State var startPosition = CGSize.zero
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Rectangle()
                .fill(Color.red)
                .stroke(Color.white, lineWidth: 0.8)
                .frame(width: 180, height: 50)
                .cornerRadius(10)
                .contentShape(Rectangle())
            Text("hello").frame(width: 180, height: 50)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
            Image(systemName: "gobackward")
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .background(.gray)
                .clipShape(Circle())
                .offset(x: 90, y: 25)
                .gesture(DragGesture().updating($dragGesture, body: {
                    value, state, _ in
                    state = value.translation
                    print(dragGesture)
                }).onEnded { value in
                    startPosition.width = startPosition.width + value.translation.width
                    startPosition.height = startPosition.height + value.translation.height
                })
        }
        .position(x: x, y: y)
        .offset(x: startPosition.width + dragGesture.width, y: startPosition.height + dragGesture.height)
    }
}

#Preview {
    MyGestureView()
}
```

If I move the gesture code to the ZStack, the flickering disappears, but I need the operation to be limited to the Image only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how you can implement **dragging of the entire view by dragging the `Image` without flickering**, limiting the operation to the Image only, without moving the gesture code to the `ZStack`. I hope this solves your query.

[image]

```
import SwiftUI

struct MyGestureView: View {
    
    @State private var startPosition: CGSize = .zero
    @State private var currentPosition: CGSize = .zero
    @GestureState private var dragState: CGSize = .zero
    
    var body: some View {
        let dragGesture = DragGesture()
            .onChanged { value in
                self.currentPosition = CGSize(
                    width: self.startPosition.width + value.translation.width,
                    height: self.startPosition.height + value.translation.height
                )
            }
            .onEnded { value in
                self.startPosition = self.currentPosition
            }
        
        ZStack {
            Rectangle()
                .fill(Color.red)
                .stroke(Color.white, lineWidth: 0.8)
                .frame(width: 180, height: 50)
                .cornerRadius(10)
                .offset(currentPosition)
            
            Text("hello")
                .frame(width: 180, height: 50)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .offset(currentPosition)
            
            Image(systemName: "gobackward")
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .background(Color.gray)
                .clipShape(Circle())
                .offset(x: 90, y: 25)
                .offset(currentPosition)
                .gesture(dragGesture)
        }
        .position(x: 200, y: 200)
    }
}


#Preview {
    MyGestureView()
}
```